# (Perhaps) An Easy Combinatorics Problem:

Tags: combinatorics

(Perhaps not so easy...)
Still have some difficulty with problems like this.

Suppose I have Box with various buttons inside. For the sake of example, let the box contain: $$[ 4 \textrm{ Red}, 5 \textrm{ Blue}, 7 \textrm{ Green} ]$$ How many distinct tuples of, say, 5 buttons can I draw from the box? In the coordinates $(r,b,g)$ I can enumerate them:
$$\{(4,0,1),(4,1,0),(3,2,0),(3,1,1),(3,0,2),(2,3,0),(2,2,1),(2,1,2),(2,0,3),(1,4,0),(1,3,1),(1,2,2),(1,1,3),(1,0,4),(0,5,0),(0,4,1),(0,3,2),(0,2,3),(0,1,4),(0,0,5)\}$$
And I count twenty.
How do I do this in general?

Given a box (multiset) of buttons $B$,
$$B = \{B_1,B_2,\cdots,B_n\}$$
composed of $n$ different styles with respective sizes $|B_j|$ how many distinct $n$-tuples can I get by drawing $k$ buttons from such a box?

From the Selected Answer:
In the general case with my notation, we want the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion
$$P(x) = \Pi_{j=1}^n \frac{1-x^{|B_j|}}{1-x} $$
 for the number of distinct $k$-tuples selected from the box.

In the cases that I'm dealing with, I think I'll have a big $n$ but maybe a smallish $k$. It appears that writing out the whole inclusion-exclusion form is a bit of a bear. But I get the general way to solve this now.

Thanks!

Comment: There are not "sets", it can be named 3-tuples better.

Comment: Use parens $(r,g,b)$ for ordered tuples.

Comment: One way to deal with the upper bounds is with inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: The key observation is that $\frac{1}{(1-x)^n}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{k+n-1}{n-1} x^k$. So you have only to multiply this by $\prod\left(1-x^{|B_j|}\right)$. That that numerator can have $2^n$ terms, which is a mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generating function approach is to write:

$$(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+\cdots + x^5)(1+x+\cdots + x^7) = \frac{(1-x^5)(1-x^6)(1-x^8)}{(1-x)^3}$$

The coefficient of $x^n$ is the number of ways of taking $n$ buttons out.

Now, $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^3} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k+2}{2}x^k$$

And: $$(1-x^5)(1-x^6)(1-x^8)=1-x^5-x^6-x^8+x^{11}+x^{13}+x^{14}-x^{19}$$

So we see the coefficient of $x^n$ is:

$$\binom{n+2}{2} - \binom{n-3}{2} - \binom{n-4}{2} - \binom{n-6}{2} + \binom{n-9}{2}+\binom{n-11}{2} +\binom{n-12}{2} - \binom{n-17}{2}$$

Where the values of the binomial $\binom{M}{2}$ is taken to be zero when $M<2$.

This is the same value you'd get with an "inclusion/exclusion" argument.

In general, if your box has $R,G,B$ buttons of each color, the formula would be:

$$\binom{n+2}{2} - \binom{n+2-R}{2} - \binom{n+2-G}{2} - \binom{n+2-B}{2} + \binom{n+2-R-G}{2}+\binom{n+2-R-B}{2} +\binom{n+2-G-B}{2} - \binom{n+2-R-G-B}{2}$$

The value $2$ gets replaced by $k-1$ and the formula gets worse with $k$ buttons, but the above approach works.

Comment: Well now I feel justified that this wasn't completely clear to me. Turns out it is not so easy.

Comment: In the original example I was choosing 5 buttons, should the $2$ in your binomial coefficients all be $5$ for that example??

Comment: No, $n=5$, so the number is $\binom{5+2}{2}-\binom{2}{2}$, since the values of $n-4<0$, and all the other terms are smaller.

Comment: Basically, if there were infinitely many buttons of each color, the answer would be $\binom{n+2}{2}$. Then we subtract examples $(r,g,b)$ where $r>4$, then examples where $g>5$, etc. Then we have to add back in cases that we subtracted twice. That's the basis for most inclusion-exclusion formula.

Comment: The "2" in my formula is one less than the number of colors. If you had $k$ colors, the base case would be $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Doh!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this is the number of weak compositions of a number. In your example you have the weak compositions of 5 into 3 parts. In general the number of weak compositions of n into k parts is $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$. In your example this gives 21. You missed {5,0,0}.

Comment: There are only 4 red buttons in the box so $\{5,0,0\}$ is an invalid tuple.

Comment: You missed the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

If Im not wrong I see 5 different values for red (from 0 to 4), 6 different values for blue and 7 different values for green.

You want that they sum exactly 5 (or starting from 1 instead of 0, 8). This is the coefficient of $x^5$ of this generating function:

$$f(x)=(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)$$

Hacking a bit trough wolfram we have that $[x^5]f(x)=20$.

---

But it is a lot faster, for this example of RGB, just evaluate the number of weak compositions for $5$ in $3$ parts and subtract the impossible ones due to the constraint.

Because the unique real constraint is the limit of $4$ on Red you only must subtract one case, the $(5,0,0)$ tuple.

Then it is $\binom{7}{2}-1=20$.

Comment: My example was a very easy version. I'm trying to do this for very much more complicated cases. But thanks,

Comment: @amcalde, yes I know. For complicated cases you must use generating functions.